# How to stop SharePoint Online (modern) logo from navigating to home.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, ootb

I have 2 different pages.

the Home.aspx is exclusive for certain group of people.

I have another page called Overview.asxp

on this page I only have 1 webpart showing a list that has a specific view on.

This is the only thing i want to let the majority of my users to see.

Now

I have made the top navigation audienced so my other users cant click and navigate all over the site as i only want them to have access to 1 page and 1 list with view permissions.

But now i have a problem that they can see everything on the site as soon as they click on the SharePoint logo as it navigates them to the Home.aspx and from there they can see a lot more than i want them to.

How can i remove the navigation from the logo?

or is there a smarter way of doing it with only using SharePoint OOTB functionalyty with zero coding?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use SPFX extension to inject a js file to SPO,and remove SharePoint Site Logo element href attribute.
[image]

Here is a demo:
https://github.com/Amos-IT/SharePoint-FrameWork-Demos/tree/master/react-application-injectjs-master

Answer (score 0):

Make Overview.asxp your Homepage. Go to your page library Right-click on the page you want to make a new Homepage and choose Make Homepage

Comment: hmm.... if i do this will the rest of the functionality not break? What will happen to everything that lives on home.aspx?

Comment: It’ll still be there to whoever accesses the page directly.  Setting the “Home/Welcome” page for the site just makes it so when you click on the logo or go to your site without a specific resource/page in the URL, the “home” page will be served up (technically SP sends a redirect to the browser).